# SQL query in a channel:next/prev_entry to output an image in a matrix column

Tags: matrix, image, query, sql, next-prev

I'm trying to create a Prev / Next navigation system using thumbnail images. The images for each entry are held in a four column matrix field (field_id = 8). I just want the first image held in the first column (col_id_38).

I'm using R.Sanchez's `{exp:parse_file_paths}` plugin to pull the image data without resorting to more embed or stashed lists.

Since `{exp:channel:prev_entry}` has to parsed outside of the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag, my current detail page template looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{segment_1}" disable="member_data|pagination" url_title="{segment_2}"}
    {title}
    {body}
    {stash:embed name="snippets:page-villanav" process="start" parse_depth="2"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The `stash:embed` which looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:next_entry channel="{segment_1}" entry_id='{exp:transcribe:entry_ids channel="villa"}' parse="inward"}
    <div class="gallery">
       <a href="{path={segment_1}}">
       {title} // This is showing the correct Next entry title
       {exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE field_id = '8' && entry_id = '{entry_id}'"}
            {entry_id}          // This is showing the correct "Next" entry_id
            {exp:parse_file_paths}
                {background_image} 
                    {image_01}  // This is showing the current entry's image filepath. Not the "Next" entry's first image filepath.
                {/background_image}
            {/exp:parse_file_paths}
        {/exp:query}
       </a>
    </div>
{/exp:channel:next_entry}
```

The problem is that, despite the query displaying the "Next" entry_id, `{exp:parse_file_paths}` is pulling the first image from the matrix field for the "current" entry.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT col_id_38 AS file FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE entry_id = '{entry_id}'"}
    {exp:parse_file_paths}
        {file}
    {/exp:parse_file_paths}
{/exp:query}
```